# Programming Paradigm to Follow

Tags: android

I am currently working on an application where the user is presented with a series of lists, clicking on each list the user is taken to another list based on his selction. Now in order to remember what the user does on each screen, i insert a series of strings into my Shared Preferences. As it turns out, as my app has about 7 8 selection screens, my whole code is just tangled up with reading and writing keys from the shared preferences.

```
air_conditioning = Session.getBoolean(SELL_AIR_CONDITIONINING) ? "1" : "0";
        power_steering = Session.getBoolean(SELL_POWER_STEERING) ? "1" : "0";
        power_locks = Session.getBoolean(SELL_POWER_LOCKS) ? "1" : "0";
        power_mirrors = Session.getBoolean(SELL_POWER_MIRROR) ? "1" : "0";
        keyless_entry = Session.getBoolean(SELL_KEYLESS_ENTRY) ? "1" : "0";
        cruise_control = Session.getBoolean(SELL_CRUISE_CONTROL) ? "1" : "0";
        navigation_system = Session.getBoolean(SELL_NAVIGATION_SYSTEM) ? "1" : "0";
        abs = Session.getBoolean(SELL_ABS) ? "1" : "0";
        am_fm_radio = Session.getBoolean(SELL_FM_AM_RADIO) ? "1" : "0";
        cassette_player = Session.getBoolean(SELL_CASSETE_PLAYER) ? "1" : "0";
        cd_player = Session.getBoolean(SELL_CD_PLAYER) ? "1" : "0";
        sun_roof = Session.getBoolean(SELL_SUN_ROOF) ? "1" : "0";
        alloy_rims = Session.getBoolean(SELL_ALLOW_RIMS) ? "1" : "0";
```

So this is basically my whole code, which looks ugly, prone to errors, and not very maintainable. I was looking for any solution that would serve me in this case.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use SharedPreferences.  Use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)s and pass the state via a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

Comment: But that looks even uglier, taking data from the first screen to the fifth screen, meaning every screen not only has to forward data from its own screen but also from previous screens.

Comment: Does it?  Bundles can store all the booleans you need.  Or, you could store it all in a single integer with each bit as a flag.  Not that much data..